# Crystal oscillator in schematics

Tags: oscillator, schematics, crystal, symbol

What the numbers 1 and 2 mean next to Crystal oscillator in hardware schematics? I tried to search online and went through about 20 lists with component symbols, but non had the numbers nor description about them.

He's a picture.

[image: Crystal oscillator with numbers 1 and 2]

Comment: Note that depending on the crystal footprint, you will see crystals with 2, 3 or even 4 pins on the schematic. The other pins may or not be connected to anything, and are generally just supports for the crystal case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since crystals usually do not have a polarity, they're just there since the CAD tool requires pin numbers for generating the PCB or writing netlists for simulators.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that too, but as i'm a newbie just wanted to check for sure. Big thanks.